# Check if property is not several different constants from a enumerator list

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum with 10 constants in it. I also have a class with a property defined like this : `MyEnumType tyleType;`

Now I want to check if `tyleType` is not ( `!=`) lets say the last 5 members of the enum. I dont want to write :

```
if(tyleType!=MyNumType.10th && tyleType! MyEnumType.9th && /* etc */)
```

What can i do in this case?

Comment: could you please include the enum def.

Comment: That aren't valid enum values

Comment: consider it pseudo code.

Comment: @UriPopov: but you want that the 10 and 9 have an inherent logic used for the order (_"the last 5 members"_)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them to a collection and use [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.90).aspx), f.e.:

```
MyNumType[] notAllowed = { MyNumType.Tenth, MyNumType.Ninth, ... };
if(!notAllowed.Contains(tyleType))
{

}
```

or store a white-list of all allowed which makes it even more readable:

```
if(allowed.Contains(tyleType)){..}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I was considering something like this. I guess I did not explain my problem completly. The number of unallowed can change during production,so I have defined a constant number in a seperate static class that I can easily change. how do I use that number to add the correct stuff to the unallowed collection?

Comment: @UriPopov: you want to have a logic which returns enum values according to a number. That doesn't sound like a good design. An enum is not an ordered collection.

Comment: @UriPopov: but you could use a `MyNumType[]` or `List<MyNumType>` which is ordered, then it's easy to return last 5 or whatever.

Comment: Thanks again for helping. I added a static MyNumType[] to my Constants class. Now if the contents of the enum change I just need to edit that one line in the Constants class. I hope this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsDefined to check if a value is in an enumerator

```
if(MyNumType.IsDefined(TypeOf(MyNumType), tyleType)
{
    //Code
}
```